# How to send a value through href?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor, syncfusion-blazor, syncfusion-blazor-sfgrid

I am trying to pass a column value through an href link, but instead of receiving the value, I am getting the column name.

```
<SfGrid DataSource="@List" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10">
        <GridColumns>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(tbl_View.Number) HeaderText="Number" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="100"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(tbl_View.Name) HeaderText="Name" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="200"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(tbl_View.PhysicalAddress) HeaderText="Address" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="200"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(tbl_View.PhysicalCity) HeaderText="City" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="150"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(tbl_View.PhysicalState) HeaderText="State" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="100"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(tbl_View.PhysicalZip) HeaderText="Zip" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="100"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(tbl_View.Group_Name) HeaderText="Group" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="150"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(tbl_View.Number) HeaderText="Number" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="150" Type="ColumnType.String">
                <Template>
                    <a href="Edit/tbl_View.Number">Edit</a>
                </Template>
            </GridColumn>
            <GridColumn HeaderText="">
                <Template>
                    <a href="MasterPolicySetup/tbl_View.Number">Master Policy</a>
                </Template>
            </GridColumn>
        </GridColumns>
    </SfGrid>
```

`

In above code, I am trying to pass tbl_View.Number to my Edit page, but there I am receiving value as "tbl_View.Number"

Can anyone help me with passing actual value?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some string interpolation and formatting:

```cs
<a href="@($"MasterPolicySetup/{tbl_View.Number}")">Master Policy</a>
```

The string interpolation and formatting is `$"MasterPolicySetup/{tbl_View.Number}"`.  It's wrapped in a `@(...)` so Razor inteprets it as C# code.  And Html expects `href=""` so iut'a quoted.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I am getting red underline at {tbl_View.Number} adn the message is "An object reference is require for the non-static field, method or property tbl_View.Number"

Comment: So what is `tbl_View`?  The error means you are referencing a non existent object.

Comment: tbl_View is a cs class containing all the above fields. I think values are being render from @ LenderList and I might have to pull selected tbl_view object Number from @LenderList but I am not sure how to do that!

Comment: You probably need to use `GridEvents` and `RowSelected` to call a method which then does the navigation.  Go read the section on the Syncfusion site.   `@nameof(tbl_View.Number)` works because it's evaluated at compile time, not runtime.  I'm no Syncfusion expert.